# Uploading an array of strings from a form to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been trying to upload an array of strings from my HTML form to my database (MongoDB).

Here is the HTML form for adding class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Create New Class</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%- include ('./partials/nav') %>
  <h1>Create New Class</h1>
  <form action="/class/add-class" method="post">
    <label for="name">Class Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>

    <label for="subjects">Enrolled Subjects:</label>
    <select id="subjects" name="subjects[]" multiple required>
      <% subjects.forEach(function(subject) { %>
        <option value="<%= subject._id %>"><%= subject.name %></option>
      <% }) %>
    </select><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Class route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Subject = require('../models/course');
const Class = require('../models/class');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const classes = await Class.find();
    res.render('class', {classes})
});

router.get('/add-class', async (req, res) => {
    const subjects = await Subject.find();
    res.render('addClass', {subjects})
});

router.post('/add-class', (req, res) => {
    const newClass = new Class ({
      name: req.body.name,
      subjects: req.body.subjects,
    });
    Class.create(newClass).then((newlycreated) => {
        req.flash('success', 'Successful');
        res.redirect('/class/add-class');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
            req.flash('error', err.message);
            res.redirect('/class/add-class');
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the Class model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const classSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    subjects: [String] // Subjects for this class
  });
  
  const Class = mongoose.model('Class', classSchema);
  
  module.exports = Class;
```

This is the subject model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    });
  
  const Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', subjectSchema);
  
  module.exports = Subject;
```

This is the subject route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Subject = require('../models/course')

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const subjects = await Subject.find();
    res.render('courses', {subjects})
});

router.get('/add-subject', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('addCourses')
});

router.post('/add-subject', (req, res) => {
    const newSubject = new Subject ({
        name: req.body.name,
    });
    Subject.create(newSubject).then((newlycreated) => {
        req.flash('success', 'successful');
        res.redirect('/subject/add-subject');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        req.flash('error', err.message);
        res.redirect('/subject/add-subject');
    })
    })

module.exports = router;
```

This is the output I keep getting.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "650c30b86c0f8320412f12ef"
  },
  "name": "SSS 1",
  "subjects": [
    "650b3c26e6e43eca75a4a9fa",
    "650b3cace6e43eca75a4a9fc",
    "650b3cbfe6e43eca75a4a9fe",
    "650b3cc6e6e43eca75a4aa00",
    "650b3cd5e6e43eca75a4aa02",
    "650b3cdde6e43eca75a4aa04",
    "650b3ce8e6e43eca75a4aa06",
    "650b3cefe6e43eca75a4aa08",
    "650b3d25e6e43eca75a4aa0c",
    "650b3d2ce6e43eca75a4aa0e",
    "650b3d68e6e43eca75a4aa18",
    "650b3d74e6e43eca75a4aa1a",
    "650b3dabe6e43eca75a4aa22"
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I used another route to see if I can bypass it, I still met a roadblock, I also tried to use `.populate()` attribute, it still returned an array of null strings

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const classData = await Class.findById(req.params.id).populate('subjects');

    // Iterate over the subjects and replace IDs with names
    const subjectsWithNames = classData.subjects.map(subject => subject.name);

    // Send the response
    res.json({
      _id: classData._id,
      name: classData.name,
      subjects: subjectsWithNames,
      __v: classData.__v
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

this was the output

```
{"_id":"650c30b86c0f8320412f12ef","name":"SSS 1","subjects":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"__v":0}
```

Comment: For [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate) to work, isn't a `ref` needed in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

In the add class form, the value is what is saved to the database. So instead of `<%= subject._id %>` change it to `<%= subject.name %>` this way, it saves the name rather than the id to the database. A prototype is shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Create New Class</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%- include ('./partials/nav') %>
  <h1>Create New Class</h1>
  <form action="/class/add-class" method="post">
    <label for="name">Class Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>

    <label for="subjects">Enrolled Subjects:</label>
    <select id="subjects" name="subjects[]" multiple required>
      <% subjects.forEach(function(subject) { %>
        <option value="<%= subject.name %>"><%= subject.name %></option>
      <% }) %>
    </select><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```